# IDA PRO run patched program from debugger without creating new exe

Tags: ida

Using IDA PRO, after making a few patched, can I run the patched program in the debugger?
What I have been doing so far is:
1.  Edit > Patch Program > Apply patch to input file…
2.  Save in a specific location
3.  Move to windows location under /programs instead of the original file
4.  Reload the patched file in IDA

This overwrites the original file. Mostly I need to put it in another location since the original may be under windows folder.
In addition if forces my to reopen IDA and load the patched file and since this is a new file I lose all my work.

Is there a way, like in Oly, to simple run the patched file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug a patched program in Ida, a simple way (for me!) is to patch it not in Ida, but in another hex editor. If you leave it its name, you will not lose your work in Ida.

In this way, you can leave Ida running and continue with the patched file, after applying "File, Load File, Reload the Input File". Your patches will show up.

Of course, you always should have saved your original file.

Comment: Can't i do the same in IDA?
I mean patch it in IDA and load it?
What I am trying to achieve is to load my patched file with all my comments and edits

Comment: Probably yes. In earlier versions of Ida (V5), there only existed "The Infamous Patch Program Menu" (the quote denotes a chapter in Chris Eagle's famous book, Ed. 2008, about that Ida version). Therefore I got used to patch not in Ida. However, the patching is independent of not losing your work in Ida.

Comment: You can patch in IDA 7

Answer (score 1):

You can not create a copy of your input file from within IDA. But if you copy it to a different location, you can point IDA to patch it there by changing the input file path in the patch program window (I verified that in IDA Free 7.0). Afterwards, you change the "Application path" and input file in the Process Options dialog inside the debugger menu to run the patched version. (I verified the presence of these settings in IDA Pro 5.6, I don't have a later commercial version at hand).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use [DebugAutoPatch](https://github.com/scottmudge/DebugAutoPatch) plugin. To install, download DebugAutoPatch.py file to IDA plugins directory. Its features:

- No need to modify any binary files to apply patches!
- Automatically synchronizes the existing "Patched bytes" database in
  IDA with any launched debug sessions.
- All patches stored in the "Patched bytes" database are applied to the
  debug session memory at "process start", before the main entry point.
- Debug hooks automatically suspend process, apply patches, and resume
  process. The process is seamless and automatic to the user.
- No extra breakpoints are added and no existing breakpoints are
  modified. The ability to disable automatic patching (and thus revert
  the binary to it's "original" state).
- These options are available in the existing "Edit > Patch program"
  menu.

Comment: It does not work for IDA 7.5

Comment: It does not work in 7.2 either. Even latest "devel" branch. As far as I can tell, latest supported version of IDA is 7.0. In the script DebugAutoPatch.py there is a note "This has been tested with IDA 7.0 - I have made attempts at backward/forward compatibility, but please report bugs for other versions". Lack of support for 7.2 and 7.5 was already reported few days ago in github issues, so hopefully eventually either author updates it or somebody will create a pull request to add support for newer IDA versions.